# Llamar elementos como texto e imágenes con javasript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5

¿Cómo puedo mandar a llamar el nombre de producto, precio e imagen? dejo foto,
a un PopUp que aparece en cuánto le das click, quiero que los datos se jalen al PopUP.

Gracias!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: agrea el codigo asi no te podremos ayudar

Comment: La pregunta es muy amplia

Answer (score 0):

Ok! les agradezco. E

```js
//intente mandar a llamar el nombre del producto de esta manera

$(".see_product").on("click",function(){
    var x = document.getElementById("Producto").id;
    document.getElementById("nombreProducto").innerHTML = x;
});
```

```html
<!-- Aquí se debe mostrar el contenido que mando a llamar -->
<div class="container">
     <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 col-lg-5">
               <div class="quickview_pro_img">
                   <img src="img/promocional/encendedor.jpg" alt="">
               </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-lg-7">
              <div class="quickview_pro_des">
                   <h4 id="Producto"></h4>
                   <h5 class="price"></h5>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
</div>




<!-- producto -->
<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 single_gallery_item women wow fadeInUpBig" data-wow-delay="0.1s">
    <div class="product-img" id="getimages">
        <img src="img/uniformes/playera.jpg" alt="title">
        <div class="product-quicview">
              <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data                                 target="#quickview"><i class="ti-plus"></i></a>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="product-description">
         <h4 class="product-price">$273.00</h4>
         <p id="nombreProducto" class="polo">Camisa Polo SOC</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

l código es el siguiente: